# Python Pandas can't select multiple columns indexed by negative numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
                   -300      -298      -296
    Time (ms)
    Fp1       -0.416809 -0.024629  0.352019
    Fp2        0.369807  0.402025  0.435756
    F7        -0.822426 -0.895215 -0.973714
    F3        -1.045553 -1.098616 -1.161518
    Fz        -0.477956 -0.462559 -0.450041
    F4         0.779856  0.741989  0.693144
    F8         0.602296  0.611537  0.630304
    T3         0.260055  0.079092 -0.118850
    C3        -1.568992 -1.612172 -1.668237
    Cz        -0.803537 -0.912913 -1.028954
    C4         0.071638  0.162218  0.250011
    T4         0.569891  0.547318  0.530495
    T5        -0.390893 -0.416855 -0.435103
    P3        -0.552106 -0.633048 -0.724976
    Pz         0.038836 -0.147223 -0.342887
    P4        -0.043076 -0.075429 -0.114958
    T6         1.018918  1.086329  1.155682
    O1         1.623878  1.332667  1.046043
    O2         0.085277 -0.191445 -0.459685
```

Row and column indexes are alright:

```
    In [111]: list(df)
    Out[111]: [-300, -298, -296]
    In [112]: print df.index.tolist()
    [u'Fp1', u'Fp2', u'F7', u'F3', u'Fz', u'F4', u'F8', u'T3', u'C3', u'Cz', u'C4', u'T4', u'T5', u'P3', u'Pz', u'P4', u'T6', u'O1', u'O2']
```

Accessing one-column ranges works fine:

```
    In [109]: df.loc["Fp1":"F4", -300]
    Out[109]:
    Time (ms)
    Fp1   -0.416809
    Fp2    0.369807
    F7    -0.822426
    F3    -1.045553
    Fz    -0.477956
    F4     0.779856
    Name: -300, dtype: float64
```

But when I try to select a multi-row and multi-column range I get an error:

```
    In [114]: df.loc["Fp1":"F4", -300:-296]
    ...
    TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [-300] of <type 'int'>
```

Well, what's the problem?

Comment: A negative index in Python has a special meaning. If you _really_ want to use it as a column name, quote it: `df.loc["Fp1":"F4", "-300":"-296"]`.

Comment: I get empty DataFrame (no columns). I have to use negative numbers because they are used in data samples I should handle.

Comment: Ok, looks like your column headers are indeed negative integer numbers, not strings. AFAIK, the only way to make slicing work is to convert them to strings with `df.columns=[str(x) for x in df.columns]` and then use quoted column names.

Comment: @DYZ, thank you, sir! I'll self-answer the question and mention you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [DMZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4492932/dyz) pointed out, it looks like one cannot use negative numbers for indexing, thus the best way to accomplish my task is to convert indexes to strings:

```
 df.columns=[str(x) for x in df.columns]
```

and then use them like this

```
 df.loc["Fp1":"F4", "-300":"-296"]
```